How to merge two values from string to new string with separation with regular expression?
Hello and thank you for your time
I have string:
{"id":"123","phone_id":"456"}
What i need, is to write regular expression that will take value of id and value of phone_id and combine to single string with single match.
So final string will be "123.456"
i was trying something like:
(?<="id":")\s*([^"]+)\.(?<="phone_id":")\s*([^"]+)
But it doesn't work.
Routing service i'm using use regex first match with golang language. That's why i can't use two regular expression and then connect them with separator. Or parse json.
So:

Is it possible?
How to make it happen?


Isn't that json? Parser? You can try: (?<="id":")\s*([^"\r\n]+)|(?<="phone_id":")\s*([^\r\n"]+)?

You may try this:
^\s*{\s*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\s*,\s*"phone_id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\s*}\s*$
Explanation:

\s* everywhere in the string is to make the string whitespace proof.

"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)" ensures to get value of the key id and it
is stored in the 1st capture group.

"phone_id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)" ensures to get value of the key
phone_id and it is stored in the 2nd capture group.


and replace the string by this:
$1.$2
Demo
Sample Source: run
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^\s*{\s*"id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\s*,\s*"phone_id"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\s*}\s*$`)
    var str = `{"id":"123","phone_id":"456"}`
    var substitution = "$1.$2"
    
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(str, substitution))
}


I think that this should work for you
"id":"([^"]+)","phone_id":"([^"]+)"

so at the end, matches will have an array of 3 values,0 for full match, 1 for id and 2 for the phone
re := regexp.MustCompile(`"id":"([^"]+)","phone_id":"([^"]+)"`)
if len(matches) == 3 {
    result := matches[1] + "." + matches[2]
    fmt.Println(result)
} else {
    fmt.Println("no matches")
}


package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := `{"id":"123","phone_id":"456"}`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`"id":"(?P<id>[^"]+)".*"phone_id":"(?P<phone_id>[^"]+)"`)

    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    if match == nil {
        fmt.Println("No match found")
        return
    }

    result := fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", match[re.SubexpIndex("id")], match[re.SubexpIndex("phone_id")])
    fmt.Println(result) // Output: 123.456
}

    enter code here


Thank you for your response, but fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s") is point, i'm not able to use.
